# log4cplus: crash on Logger::shutdown on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, logging, dll, log4cplus

When I call

```
log4cplus::Logger::shutdown();
```

it throws an exception `Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 02BF0000, 02B71170 )` on deconstructors of log4cplus's classes.

I'm using log4cpp 1.2.x (from current 1.2.x branch) and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I compiled my application to work on Win32 architecture, but it crashes when compiled for x64, too. I created log4cplus as an DLL file and added the `log4cplus.lib` file as additional dependency to my application to link it load-time. I have some other DLL files which are run-time dynamically loaded into the application. The run-time loaded DLLs also depend on log4cplus.

log4cplus's logging system is initialized as early as possible to support logging in every stage of my application (as first call in the main method).

Is it an issue with mixing load-time and run-time loaded DLL files?

PS: I have some basic knowledge about C++ programming.

**edit:**

OS: Windows 8.1 x64

Application type:

- GUI application over WinAPI (custom preloader, update mechanism and user login)
- native calling jvm.dll to create a JavaVM (main application after user logged in, is written in Java)

It runs into an exception at after calling `PatternLayout::~PatternLayout()` before creating a JavaVM.

**edit2:**

The structure of my project solution is:

- app (executable)
- xcom (dll library for communication with Java)
- systemgtk (dll library for registry access and GUI)
- service (executable, background updater, runs as Windows service)
- log4cplus

The projects app, xcom, systemgtk and serivce loads log4cplus at init time, systemgtk and xcom are loaded at run time inside the app and service.

I initialize log4cplus in the app.exe and want to close it inside the systemgtk.dll.

**edit3:**

Okay, it seems to be a build configuration issue. I don't know how, but I fixed this issue.

Comment: Few questions:

1. At what time are you calling `log4cplus::Logger::shutdown();` Is it still inside `main()`? 

2. What exact version of log4cplus 1.2.0 is this? Is it a RC or the release itself?

3. What does *log4cplus's logging system is initialized as early as possible to support logging in every stage of my application* mean exactly?

4. What version of Windows is this running on?

Comment: Well, this looks like "[Crash in ~per\_thread\_data · Issue #155 · log4cplus/log4cplus](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/issues/155)" which is fixed but after 1.2.0 was released.

Comment: @wilx 1. I call ``log4cplus::Logger::shutdown();`` inside a WinAPI GUI loop (and I'm not sure it's the same thread, probably another thread). I didn't wrote the application, I have to extend it with logging; 2. I'm using release 1.2.0; 3. I initialized it right as the first thing in the main method; 4. Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: @wilx I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Well, it is nearly impossible for me to tell what is going on. I would suggest trying to check out the latest [1.2.x branch](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/tree/1.2.x) and try to build with it.

Comment: @wilx The latest 1.2.x branch have the same issue. Does log4cplus have problems on shutdown function when it's called from another lib or another thread than the initialize function?

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the "Configuration Properties->General" panel if "Use of MFC" is set to "Use MFC in a Shared DLL", the error will be gone; but if it's set to "Use MFC in a Static Library", the error will show up.